# Setting Font options in heatmap.2

Tags: r

Does anybody have any clue on how to set different font options (size, style, family, etc.) of labels (x and y) in `heatmap.2`. I can manipulate the font size with the `cexCol` and `cexRow` parameters, but still I don't find any parameter for complete font manipulation.
Any suggestion is highly appreciable.

Comment: Please define the term "complete font manipulation". I know from experience that a much of the annotation in heatmap.2 is hard-coded, so you need to be very specific about what you want.

Comment: heatmap.2 is pretty bad at scaling itself to the situation.   if you have lots of stuff on either axis, the labels start overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

This is the code inside heatmap.2 that creates the (main) axis annotation:

```
axis(1, 1:nc, labels = labCol, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0, 
    cex.axis = cexCol)
if (!is.null(xlab)) 
    mtext(xlab, side = 1, line = margins[1] - 1.25)
axis(4, iy, labels = labRow, las = 2, line = -0.5, tick = 0, 
    cex.axis = cexRow)
if (!is.null(ylab)) 
    mtext(ylab, side = 4, line = margins[2] - 1.25)
```

Once you decide what you want, then hacking that code will get you a specific result. If you want the entire function rewritten, then ..... hire a consultant

Comment: Just type `heatmap.2` at the console once you have loaded the gplots-package that contains it.